Keyboard freezes when closing lid
Dell Inc. Inspiron 5570 laptop, keyboard freezes when lid is closed.
How to fix it onUbuntu 22.04.4 LTS?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
